# Como mostrar cuantos movimientos se toma en completar el puzzle de las torre de Hanoi dependiendo de la cantidad de discos?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy practicando la recursion resolviendo el rompecabezas de torres de hanoi.

Llegue a una solucion optima, aqui esta mi codigo:

```
using namespace std;


// funcion recursiva
void torreDeHanoi (int numeroDiscos, char barraOrigen, char barraAuxiliar, char barraDestino){
    if (numeroDiscos > 0){
        torreDeHanoi (numeroDiscos - 1, barraOrigen, barraDestino, barraAuxiliar);
        cout << "El disco " << numeroDiscos << " se mueve desde la barra" << " " << barraOrigen << " hacia la barra" << " " << barraDestino << endl;
        torreDeHanoi (numeroDiscos-1,barraAuxiliar, barraOrigen, barraDestino);
    }
}


int main () {
    int numeroDiscos;
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de discos" << endl;
    cin >> numeroDiscos;
    

   torreDeHanoi(numeroDiscos, 'A', 'B', 'C'); //A es la barra inicial, B es la barra axuliar, C es la barra destino
   cout << endl;
}
```

Aqui esta el output en el caso de n = 3:
[image: n = 3:]

Mi pregunta es, como podria mostrar en pantalla la cantidad de movimientos que se tomo en completar el puzzle dependiendo del numero de discos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes devolver la cantidad de movimientos en cada recursión:

```
int torreDeHanoi (int numeroDiscos, char barraOrigen, char barraAuxiliar, char barraDestino)
{
    int movimientos = 0;
    if (numeroDiscos > 0) {
        ++movimientos;

        movimientos += torreDeHanoi(numeroDiscos - 1, barraOrigen, barraDestino, barraAuxiliar);

        cout
            << "El disco " << numeroDiscos
            << " se mueve desde la barra " << barraOrigen
            << " hacia la barra" << " " << barraDestino << endl;

        movimientos += torreDeHanoi(numeroDiscos - 1, barraAuxiliar, barraOrigen, barraDestino);
    }

    return movimientos;
}
```

Así este código:

```
int main()
{
    int movimientos = torreDeHanoi(3, 'A', 'B', 'C');

    cout << "Se ha resuelto en " << movimientos << " movimientos.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

[Muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##lVLLbsIwEDzbX7FKDwQRCqhHHhItlXrroddeXGeBlZI18gNVqvj21AktdZA49GLLo9nxzNj6cBjrSvGuae6IdRVKhAUZ5y2qeiVlcMQ7YFWjOyiN4Hw5l1JOJrANrMkwWNTBOjoqSezBG2txgy@KDUHeIhxqtGZDThtXgN4rCx/KWvVqaYecIuvwSRUpm2IbdJ7YDOWXFK1abY5UE7I3DpYwnUd0C3l6B6xgOoRIF6NRwo6uhUinR8srsz2RMcyKvs/UTtE3PGwrEUKb4OMmFgvInisoWyXIIB5T6V8GOIQ64BGhRBdbr9RZ9DyRXH0Z2CtN6sLraFnC/vHWnpHL6n@Bx7Pi6g1uho9pxSmKW/TBMvQ6jnj3DWpFnN94tNRE/lDAYD2Iy2O7PA3aKrsiu3RvGEPHH@YCVt7EWOe4qV5XQgLcv3M2/3MXf8ipab4B):

> ```
> El disco 1 se mueve desde la barra A hacia la barra C
> El disco 2 se mueve desde la barra A hacia la barra B
> El disco 1 se mueve desde la barra C hacia la barra B
> El disco 3 se mueve desde la barra A hacia la barra C
> El disco 1 se mueve desde la barra B hacia la barra A
> El disco 2 se mueve desde la barra B hacia la barra C
> El disco 1 se mueve desde la barra A hacia la barra C
> Se ha resuelto en 7 movimientos.
> ```